# React tsx using Grid giving ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: reactjs

As part of React, I am using tsx.
I am using Grid and including the Grid on the page giving
**ReferenceError: require is not defined**

I have installed datagrid using
npm install --save @ux-uitoolkit-react/datagrid

Then did
npm update

Then
npm run build
Then
npm run preview

- **Cars.tsx**

```
    import { FC } from 'react';
    import { Col, Container, Row } from '@ux-uitoolkit-react/layout';
    import { DataGrid } from '@ux-uitoolkit-react/datagrid';
    import { AllModules } from '@ux-uitoolkit-react/datagrid-modules';
    import { DataToolbar } from '@ux-uitoolkit-react/datatoolbar';

    const data = [
        { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000, color: 'Red' },
        { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000, color: 'Blue' },
        { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000, color: 'Yellow' },
    ];

    const gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [
            { headerName: 'Make', field: 'make' },
            { headerName: 'Model', field: 'model' },
            { headerName: 'Price', field: 'price' },
            { headerName: 'Color', field: 'color' },
        ],
    };

    export const CarsGrid: FC = () =>  {

            return (
                <DataToolbar id={`Toolbar`} style={{ height: '250px' }}>
                    <DataGrid
                        modules={AllModules}
                        id={`Grid`}
                        rowData={data}
                        gridOptions={gridOptions}
                    />
                </DataToolbar>
            );

    }

    export const Cars: FC = () => {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <h1>List of Cars</h1>

                        <CarsGrid/>

                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    };

    export default Cars;
```

```
    npm install --save @ux-uitoolkit-react/datagrid
    npm update
    npm run build
    npm run preview
```